# ¿Como poner un tamaño maximo a una fuente?

Tags: css, fuentes, font-size

En mi caso, quiero ponerle un tamaño maximo a unos iconos que coloque con boostrap, pero si le pongo font-size en % o vw se agrandan mucho, y si pongo en px cuando achico me quedan muy grandes, y me gustaria que no pasen de sierto tamaño al agrandar o achicar mi pagina.
html:

```
<nav class="barraLateral">
  <section>
    <a href="#"><img src="./imagenes/Lnf.png" alt="LogoL"></a>
  </section>
  <section class="barraLE">
    <a href=""><i class="bi bi-house-heart-fill"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="bi bi-code-slash"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i></a>
  </section>
  <section class="barraLR">
    <a href=""><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="bi bi-github"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i></a>
  </section>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.barraLE {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.barraLE a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso puedes usar la función [clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp), cuyo primer valor es el minimo valor permitido, el segundo es el valor y el 3ro es el maximo permititdo

Por otro lado veo frecuentemente un error muy comun, que aclararé por las dudas. Las unidades relativas al `font-size` son relativas al `font-size` del padre, no al tamaño de este (ni al `width` ni al `height`)

Acá un ejemplo:

- Los 2 primeros texto son del mismo tamaño `20px` porque es el tamaño minimo definido en el `clamp`
- Igualmente los 2 últimos, también son del mismo tamaño `30px`, por es el máximo.

Es decir el texto solo puedes variar entre 20px y 30px

```css
#padre1 { font-size:5px}
#padre2 { font-size:10px}
#padre3 { font-size:30px}
#padre4 { font-size:60px}

span{
 font-size:clamp(20px,2em,30px)
}
```

```html
<div id="padre1"><span>AAA</span></div>
<div id="padre2"><span>AAA</span></div>
<div id="padre3"><span>AAA</span></div>
<div id="padre4"><span>AAA</span></div>
```